# What does it mean for datasets to be independent?

Tags: definition, independence

I want to simulate some data with which to test some independence tests in a software package. To simulate the appropriate data, I need to understand which properties are required of that data.

### Definition 1

The documentation of the package I am testing describes independence testing as follows:

> Consider random variables $X$ and $Y$ with distributions $F_X$ and $F_Y$ respectively, and joint distribution is $F_{XY}=F_{Y|X}F_X$. When performing independence testing, we are seeing whether or not $F_{Y|X}=F_Y$. That is, we are testing
> $$
> H_0:F_{XY}=F_XF_Y \\
> H_A:F_{XY} \neq F_XF_Y
> $$

This fits with my understanding of statistical independence for a single outcome:
$$
P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B)
$$
and
$$
P(A|B) = P(A)
$$

### Definition 2

**What confuses me** is how these descriptions connect with another description of what (at least one) of these tests does:

> ...the function tests whether two multivariate samples were independently drawn from the same distribution

This is similar to Wikipedia's description of the purpose of [permutation testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_test#Method), which after some inspection of the source code, is what the independence tests use.

> The permutation test is designed to determine whether ... the data drawn from $A$ is from the same distribution as the data drawn from $B$

### My question is...

Is definition 2, that independence of datasets means that samples are drawn from different distributions, compatible with the definition 1? Are they distinct concepts, or are they related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second test is *not* testing whether the data were drawn independently. Notice that the opening of the Wikipedia article states the null hypothesis as being that the two samples were drawn *from the same distribution*.

That is, the first test will tell you whether $F_{XY}(x, y) = F_X(x) F_Y(y)$, the second test will tell you whether $F_X(x) = F_Y(x)$.

Comment: Is $FX(x)=FY(x)$ equivalent to saying $FX(x)=FY(y)$?

Comment: The latter is a kind of sloppy notation, because the important thing is that evaluating the two functions at the same point gives the same value, and in the latter $x$ and $y$ are two different variables. Would it be clearer if I wrote $F_X(z) = F_Y(z)$ instead?

Comment: Ah yes. I see now. Thank you! I would give you an upvote, but my rep is too low I think.